# How does a Wordpress plugin behave on Azure Websites?

Tags: azure, wordpress, azure-web-app-service

When running Wordpress on a physical server I can access it as admin and install a new plugin. When I'm running it on Azure Websites if I access as admin and install a new plugins, I'm not sure if Azure will keep the plugins once I'm dealing with a cloud plataform and the cloud supposedly can change my app to other node/vm at any time. On the other hand, the initial configuration of the Wordpress created by the Azure Gallery already has some plugins, suggesting that it works as expected.

So do I need to clone the repo and install the plugins on my wordpress locally or I can just install the plugins directly? Does anyone know the suitable way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

We maintain Wordpress on Azure websites through the WP Admin panel, including all updates, themes and plugins.  We install locally just for development, styling and testing - then install or overwrite as required.